# Adding a div from an external file with a function?

Tags: jquery

I'm creating an faq page for a work intranet site and would like to have one file with questions and one file with the associated answers so instead of having to edit multiple different pages I can just have 2 pages to edit. I've got it working so that when the question is clicked the answer displays under the question on the faq.php page:

```
<ul>
<li><a id="abc" href="#"> question here</a></li>
<div id="abc1"></div>
</ul>
```

on my external jQuery script page:

```
$(function() {
    $('#abc').click(function() {
        $('#abc1').load('test.php #xyz');
});
```

it works just fine... is there a way to put this into a function so I don't have to write a new block of jQuery for every new question div id?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use ID. **ID's should be unique.** So if you hook up your functionality with ID selector, It is going to be specific. We need some generic solution.

Use a css class selector so that you can apply it for many items. So i will make a small adjustment to the markup like this.

```
 <ul>
    <li>
        <a id="abc" href="#" class="q"> question here</a>
        <div id="abc1" class="a"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="abc2" href="#" class="q"> question 2 here</a>
        <div id="abc2" class="a"></div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Script

```
$(function() {
    $('.q').click(function() {
      var item=$(this);
      item.parent().find(".a").load('test.php #xyz');
});
```

If you want to pass the Id of the clicked question to the test.php page to get the answer for that specific question, you can send the ID (of a tag)

```
$(function() {
    $('.q').click(function() {
      var item=$(this);
      var clickedQuestionId=item.attr("id");
      item.parent().find(".a").load("test.php?qid="+clickedQuestionId+"#xyz");
    });
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle demo( used static text in answer instead of calling ajax method)
http://jsfiddle.net/EcWFm/11/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong because when I use the code from your second example and click on the question both the answers display under both of the questions?

Comment: @Jake: There was a syntax error. I fixed it and added a jsfiddle.

Comment: wasn't sure which html you wanted so here is a fiddle with the questions and the html from the external test.php page http://jsfiddle.net/jake123/Pv9qS/